# Create Groupboxes conditionally from lists

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgroupbox

I have the following lists that are automatically generated with which I want to create groupboxes with PyQt5:

```
Country = ['France', 'France', 'Germany', 'Austria', 'Austria','Spain', 'Portugal','Portugal','Portugal','Spain']
Date = ['26.04', '14.05', '25.02', '18.04','15.06','18.09', '15.05', '28.03', '09.09', '10.10']
Lines = ['Line1', 'Line2', 'Line3', 'Line4', 'Line5', 'Line6', 'Line7', 'Line8', 'Line9', 'Line10']
```

I know that I can get this type of Groupbox that would look like a table with the following code:

[image: Unified_groupbox]

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        Country = ['France', 'France', 'Germany', 'Austria', 'Austria','Spain', 'Portugal','Portugal','Portugal','Spain']
        Date = ['26.04', '14.05', '25.02', '18.04','15.06','18.09', '15.05', '28.03', '09.09', '10.10']
        Lines = ['Line1', 'Line2', 'Line3', 'Line4', 'Line5', 'Line6', 'Line7', 'Line8', 'Line9', 'Line10']


        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Window')
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainB  = QHBoxLayout()


        self.GB1 = QGroupBox("")
        self.GB1.setStyleSheet('QGroupBox {'
                 'border: 0px solid gray; }')
        self.GB1.setFixedHeight(250)
        self.GB1.setFixedWidth(250)

        self.mainB.addWidget(self.GB1)

        grid1 = QGridLayout()
        for i in range(0,len(Country)):
           grid1.addWidget(QLabel(Country[i]), i, 0)
           grid1.addWidget(QLabel(Date[i]), i, 1)
           grid1.addWidget(QLabel(Lines[i]), i, 2)


        self.GB1.setLayout(grid1)

        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainB)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

However, I would like to create Groupboxes that would combine elements that correspond to a same 'Country' in the first list when that country occurs successively.

It might be better to visualize it by seeing an example of what I intend to do below:

[image: Separated_groupboxes]

Is there a way to generate those groupboxes automatically to achieve the intended result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to the solution is to group the data, in this case I use a dictionary where each key is the country, and its value is a list of date and line tuples.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        Country = ['France', 'France', 'Germany', 'Austria', 'Austria','Spain', 'Portugal','Portugal','Portugal','Spain']
        Date = ['26.04', '14.05', '25.02', '18.04','15.06','18.09', '15.05', '28.03', '09.09', '10.10']
        Lines = ['Line1', 'Line2', 'Line3', 'Line4', 'Line5', 'Line6', 'Line7', 'Line8', 'Line9', 'Line10']

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)

        d = {}
        for country, date, line in zip(Country, Date, Lines):
            if country in d:
                d[country].append((date, line))
            else:
                d[country] = [(date, line)]

        for country, content in d.items():
            groub_box = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(country)
            grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
            groub_box.setLayout(grid_layout)
            lay.addWidget(groub_box)

            for row, (date, line) in enumerate(content):
                grid_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(date), row, 0)
                grid_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(line), row, 1)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and the explanation. It is working as intended.

Comment: I don't know if I should open another question for this but I wonder how it would be done if had another list ```Colors = ['R', 'G', 'R', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'R', 'R', 'G', 'R']``` that determines an image to be added to a label that would be added inside the groupbox. 
Specifically something that would reproduce the following: 
```if Colors[0] == 'R':
QLabel().setPixmap(QPixmap("./Icons/Red.png"))``` or Green for 'G'.

Comment: @SdJunk First I recommend that you try to solve it, that will serve as learning. When you can not implement it then you just go to SO as a last resort. Many consider (and it is also my case) that the OP must show an effort in solving your problem, in your initial question I saw an effort on your part, but in your last request I do not see it.

Comment: I totally understand that. I have been trying to deconstruct the code from the moment I got your first answer so I can understand how to implement it. From looking at the code, I think I should be looking at the last part of the code but I have a hard time determining how exactly I should update said label before adding it to the layout. I have tried to setPixmap while adding it to the layout, but obviously it is not working. I will keep trying to solve it in the meantime.

Comment: @SdJunk Analyze what each line of my code does, if you realize I have left spaces for it to be observed that there are blocks of code, so analyze what each block of code does (the old school tricks to understand a code is to print as modify the variables in each part of the code, or comment on a certain part to understand that part of the code). Also I suppose you should know basic python, like for example that it does zip, the operation of a dictionary, which does enumerate, etc, if you do not know it then better invest your time in learning basic python before Qt.

Comment: OK. Thank you again. I will work on it. I have to admit that you are right on the fact that I lack knowledge in some basic python as I have been needing and using  it for a very specific purpose and tended to not focus much on what was not "relevant" to the task. But now that I am mostly finished with what I needed it for initially, I have more time to plug the holes that I left up to now.